# Unable to embed iframe in Joomla

Tags: iframe, joomla, tinymce, google-forms

I'm trying to embed Google form in Joomla page. For some reason, it's stripping  tag, as soon as I save the page.

Tried with below,

1. With JCEditor - Enabled iframe in media content
2. With TinyMCE - Removed iframe from restricted content
3. Enabled "No Filtering" for Super User in Joomla Global Configuration

Still, no luck.

Joomla version - 3.6.2

Any help here would be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Rather than embedding the form in an article directly you can use a module called a "Wrapper" and then associate that wrapper module with the Article / Menu item you are trying to display it with.

To create a module go to (Extensions > Modules) in Joomla Admin then do "New" to have the module placed around the article choose the appropriate "position" then make sure to set the "Menu Assignment" to "Only on the pages selected"

[image]

If you need it in the middle of an article you can learn more about how to do that here - How do you put a module inside an article?...
https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F

Answer (score 0):

Try setting editor to: "NONE"

Use Chrome when performing the save, I have seen this to be a browser issue.